# How to implement SaveChanges() method at Service layer level in ASP.NET Core MVC app?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, design-patterns, asp.net-core-mvc

Inside the project I work on (ASP.NET Core with EF), I have implemented **Repository Pattern** with **UnitOfWork**, and in my UnitOfWork class I have the `SaveChanges()` method.

Now I must add a new layer of **services** which will contain the app logic and the calls to the repository classes. All the things were good until I reached the SaveChanges() method.

I **don't** want to call `UnitOfWork.SaveChanges()` at the end of every method from my service classes. Another thing that I want to **avoid** is to call the `SaveChanges()` when all the modifications are done, lets say `EmployeeService.SaveChanges()`, but the changes are made by multiple services, eg: `ShopService`, `ClientService` and `EmployeeService`. To call the `EmployeeService.SaveChanges()` for me it seems contra intuitive because the changes that should be saved are also related to `ShopService` and `ClientService`, not just with the service class from where the save method is called.

In order to make a summary of my problem, I could say that I'm asking for a solution to save the changes at the service layer level when I have multiple changes made by multiple services. I want to save them just once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

UnitOfWork should call BeginTransaction/CommitTransaction.  Each Service can then  call SaveChanges as necessary.  For instance, a Service may need to add an entity and use its database-generated ID, which requires immediately calling SaveChanges.

Comment: Agree, but I have many cases when I must perform multiple changes and I don't want to make a save operation immediately after each change. I want to save them all at the end. If I have 3 services that are making changes it's not very intuitive to call the SaveChanges() method just from a single service to save all the changes made by other services

Comment: What's wrong with having each Service call SaveChanges?  But I agree, you probably should either always call SaveChanges in each service, or only call SaveChanges at the end.  Either may work for your particular application, but the general solution is for each service to call SaveChanges.